# Need to copy single file to all subfolders recursively

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Please can someone help me create a powershell or CMD script, as simple as possible (1 line?) that will do the following...

-Take file (c:\test.txt)
-Copy to ALL subfolders within a given folder, including multiple levels deep
eg, c:\test1\1\2\3\  and c:\test2\6\7\8\
-Without overwriting that file if it already exists
-Not changing ANY existing files. Just adding the original txt file if it doesn't exist.

I've tried a bunch of scripts I found online, changing them, but have been unsuccessful. Either it overwrites existing files, or doesn't go multiple levels deep, or skips all the folders between top/bottom levels, or throws errors.  I give up.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: use `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Directory` parameter to get all the dirs in a dir tree. then iterate thru the list, check for the file, if not there, copy it. ///// that seems to be what you want. what code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\temp\1 -Directory
$file = "c:\temp\test.txt"

foreach($folder in $folders){
    $checkFile = $folder.FullName + "\test.txt"
    $testForFile=Test-Path -Path $checkFile
    if(!$testForFile){
        Copy-Item $file -Destination $folder.FullName
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner, but here you go:

```
$rootFolder = 'PATH OF FOLDER CONTAINING ALL THE SUBFOLDERS'
$fileToCopy = 'c:\test.txt'
$fileName   = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fileToCopy)
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath $fileName) -PathType Leaf)) {
        Copy-Item -Path $fileToCopy -Destination $_.FullName
    }
}
```